# Resize column in SlickGrid

Tags: backbone.js, slickgrid

I have the following SlickGrid:

```
 var eligibleProductsGrid = new recline.View.SlickGrid({
                model:dataset,
                el:'#selectorModal #selectorModalContainer #selectorModalGrid',
                state:{
                    fitColumns:true,
                    hiddenColumns: ['id', 'mrid', 'distributedQuantity' ,'qMeasureUnit'],
                    gridOptions:{
                        enableColumnReorder:false,
                        gridIdCSS: arguments[0].gridIdCSS ? arguments[0].gridIdCSS: "eligpprodGs9999",
                    }
                }
            });
```

and i want to rezise the width of the third column.

I've tried doing this:

```
var cols =  this.eligibleProductsGrid.getColumns();
cols[2].width = 520;
this.eligibleProductsGrid.setColumns(cols);
```

but i have an error saying that `getColumns()` is not a function.

Any ideas? Thanks!